# Attach OnClickListeners to the Slidemenu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I've implemented `ActionBarSherlock` and the [Slidemenu by jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my android application. Everything seems to work quite well; the menu is showing when I fling my finger over the screen and also when I press the application icon in the `ABS`. What I did was to include the `ABS` project as a library to the `Slidemenu` as described. Once this was done, I added the `slidemenu` as a library to my existing android project. So I have my class declaration:

```
public class Home extends SlidingActivity
```

Where the `SlidingActivity` extends `SherlockActivity`. All this is described at the GitHub link above.

What I've been struggling with, is how I can implement the menu. The `ListView` inside the SlideMenu should contain some sort of menu items which has a OnClickListener attached. So when the user opens this slidemenu, it will present a menu like:

1. Home
2. Settings
3. About

Once the user presses on of this items, a new `Activity` should be launched.

Can somebody give me a hint or the source code to where I should implement such logic?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14360860/1323014, If you need more info, aske me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the behindContent with a ListFragment. This is how you'll have an onClickListner. The Fragment will handle it.