# Android Sliding fragment instead of menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer, android-sliding

I would like to implement an activity with 2 fragments in tablet app. Fragment A on left and second fragment B with some additional info on the right. Lets say each fragment has half of the screen width. Now I would like to add the option to slide the right fragment B to the right side of screen and let the fragment only e.g. 10 % of width (so fragment A can expand to 90%).

So fragment A now can has more space and fragment B can be slided to the middle back again. I would like to ask if there is a library that can help me or if there is already functional solution of this.

I have never worked with SlidingDrawer that seems to be right but now it is deprecated.

Comment: I think https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu could work for this, you may have to adapt it a bit but it seems like the functionality is most of what you want already.

Answer (score 1):

Download this library:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Check here how to implement:
[Dynamic UI with sliding menu and actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274676/dynamic-ui-with-sliding-menu-and-actionbarsherlock/14360860#14360860)