# Display an android activity (not view) in a sliding side menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, slidingmenu

I'm using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) lib to implement a sliding side menu. I can add a list view, or other views to the menu as: `menu.setMenu(R.layout.static_list_layout);` and it's working perfectly as wanted.

My needs are more than a static list, I used to have an activity that relies on an empty list_view and programmatically fill up the list according to user profile, the contents are dynamic.

Just as facebook left menu, where user groups are listed. I want to attach this same activity to dynamically fill the list in the menu. Is this possible? Any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you find a way to do it you shouldn't use an Activity for what you are describing.

The better option is to use a Fragment class, a quick search found me an example here:
[Dynamic UI with sliding menu and actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274676/dynamic-ui-with-sliding-menu-and-actionbarsherlock/14360860#14360860)

The good thing about fragments is that they have pretty much the same lifecycle as activities so you get all the things that an activity has.

The other option is to use your own view (that is extend it).

you can create a class that extends FrameLayout for example and add an inflated view to it. This will also enable you to write additional logic based on dynamic properties.

However i suggest you to look into fragments and do it the "fragments" way.

Answer (score 1):

Activities span the full screen, this is not possible.
You can try to use a fragment however.

Comment: and how can I add list items dynamically?

Comment: Just the same with fragments. Take your existing list filling code etc and use it. You can always call `list.removeAllChildren()` to make it empty again. You could also use different list adapters that you set each time the menu has to change.